# Reading csv values as.date returns NA

Tags: r, csv, na

I'm trying to read csv values as.date using R. My csv file only contain one column with the dates listed as following :

```
     x
1   20010101
2   20010117
3   20010201
4   20010217
5   20010301
6   20010317
7   20010401
8   20010417
9   20010501
10  20010517
```

And the script i used is :

```
d <- read.csv("D:\\test.csv", header = TRUE, sep = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> str(d)
'data.frame':   345 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: int  20010101 20010117 20010201 20010217 20010301 20010317 20010401 20010417 20010501 20010517 ...
date_EVI <- as.Date(paste(d$x), "%mm%dd%YYYY")
```

But the returns are all NA.

Any advice please?

Comment: You could try `date_EVI <- as.Date(d$x, "%Y%m%d")` .

Comment: and use `as.character` instead of `paste`, better use a function which job is to coerce type than a higher level function for this case.

Comment: See `as.Date` (more directly, see `?strptime`)

Comment: @RHertel usual format for date command, but I didn't check against R strptime indeed, first thing was the wrong order.

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai , as.character worked it out !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your date format is wrong. Try `%Y%m%d`.

For example:

```
dates <- c("20010101", "20010117", "20010517")
as.Date(dates, "%Y%m%d")
```

And applied to your code:

```
d <- read.csv("D:\\test.csv", header = TRUE, sep = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
date_EVI <- as.Date(as.character(d$x), "%Y%m%d")
```

Comment: i have 345 dates, if you know of easy way to write them the way you mentioned, please let me know it....

Comment: `as.Date` is a function that takes a list of values. In your case, `d` column `x` is a list of strings, so do: `as.Date(d$x, "%Y%m%d")`

Answer (score -1):

Thanks alot for all the suggestions.

change this line :

```
`date_EVI <- as.Date(paste(d$x), "%mm%dd%YYYY")`
```

To this:

```
 date_EVI <- as.Date(as.character(d$x),  "%Y%m%d")
```

Has perfectly solved the problem.
Thanks [Tensibai](http://Tensibai)